# Why do I get "N/A" when using xpath in Google sheets-importxml, but not in Chrome HTML debugger?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on a webscraping project on the following website http://www.comune.taranto.it/index.php/avvisi. I would like to extract the content of the first table and insert them into a Google Spreadsheet. I'm trying to use different xpath codes:

```
//td[contains(@class,'list-title')]/a/text()
```

```
//tbody[1]/tr/td/a/text()
```

```
//tr[contains(@class,'cat-list')]/td/a/text()
```

All of these codes work when I use the HTML debbugger of Chrome, but when I paste them into IMPORTXML, it returns N/A. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website http://www.comune.taranto.it/index.php/avvisi returns invalid markup.
I just tried to fetch the website from console:

```
await fetch('http://www.comune.taranto.it/index.php/avvisi').then(res => res.text())
```

And I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it-it" lang="it-it" dir="ltr">
<head>
...
```

So `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` should not be there. That's why `IMPORTXML` can't parse it. To verify it I just temporary hosted website on [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/html) with and without that xml declaration. And `IMPORTXML` was able to parse when the website was without it.

So what's the solution?

- If you can then change the website to return a valid html
- Or use Google App Scripts and write the code to parse the website
- Or use some kind of proxy website that returns valid html